# Android. Add button to extended View

Tags: android, class, button

its possible to add button to extended view class? I have new class which extends View and want to add new button. How I could solve it?

Ok, I get it. One more question, Its possible to mix activity with onDraw method? I want to create signature activity and add button to save it.

Comment: you cant .. othewise extend with Viewgroup

Answer (score 0):

Your custom View needs to extend `ViewGroup` or another class that extends `ViewGroup`, such as `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibilty would be getting the View and adding an Element with

```
      this.addView(.../*new View*/)
```

Be sure, that the pointer this is the created View.
Is that what you mean?